# Alternative major improvements for Agricola

Tags: house-rules, agricola

Are there any (official/unofficial) alternatives to the major improvements in Agricola?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Z-Man Games has [Farmers of the Moor](http://www.zmangames.com/boardgames/files/agricola/Of%20the%20Moor/OftheMoor_Rules.pdf) as an expansion.

Answer (score 3):

Also the [Biogas plant](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/111165/agricola-biogas-plant-promo-card) major improvement that was a Spiel 2011 promotional card from Lookout games